# How do i make a curve follow a terrain ? GEO Nodes

Tags: procedural, geometry-nodes

So I making this spikes like thing which follow a curve to define there path and I want that curve to follow a terrain basically terrains ridges and all ups and downs so how do I do that procedurally with geo nodes ?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can project curve points on terrain using `Raycast` node

[image]

[image]